# New to Zend Framework 2. How to structure modules correctly?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I'm new to MVC and ZF2.

I carried out their tutorial successfully to build a basic app. (http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.1/en/user-guide/overview.html). In that tutorial they create a module called 'Album' to add/edit/delete music albums.

What I want to do is create an application that will have various functions, such as user account administration, system config, etc. I'm aware via reading other posts that you don't need to create a new module for each function, rather grouping them under one using entities.

With that in mind I set out creating my first module 'User' using this structure but I'm not sure if I'm doing it right. Structure I have at the moment is:

```
/module
 /Application
  /config
  /language
  /view
  /src
   /Application
    /Controller
     /UserController.php
    /Entity
     /User.php
     /UserTable.php
    /view
     /user
      /user
       /index
```

If you want a look at the code check out the repo at https://bitbucket.org/newvisionjames/zf2-test/overview

Specific questions I have are:

1) I have two 'view' directories at the moment, pretty sure that's wrong..which one is correct, if either?

2) In the ZF2 tutorial they create two php files under `/model` called `Album.php` and `AlbumTable.php`. I have reflected this is my `/Entity` folder. Is this direct transfer correct? Does having an `/Entity` directory render the `/model` not necessary?

Overall what I'm trying to do is get set up with this framework so that it's working and I'll be able to learn from there but right now I'm stuck! Any helpful answers or pointers to useful resources will be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

ZF2 follows PSR-0 standard which also improves the ability for other framework modules to interact with ZF2.  To learn more about PSR-0 standard, take a look here: https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-0.md

With your example above mentioning user, you most likely would keep user in it's own module due to the nature of "user".  Does the user just contain a class to represent the user or does it include hooks for authorization and authentication etc?  Also how is the routes handled?  Although user may seem simple at first glance it's usually something that is placed in it's own module.

And that is so you can re-use / share your module with others.  Generally whenever I build an app it would be moved into multiple modules depending on where the functionality fits.  Then between modules if I need access to another module I will make use of the service locator to access those methods.

For instance under the application module I may want to reference the user's first name, i can call the user module service to then show me the user's details.  This simplifies your code a lot.

To answer your questions directly though:

1. I have two 'view' directories at the moment, pretty sure that's wrong..which one is correct, if either?

Answer:
Based on your posted directory structure only the top level "view" directory looks correct in a "ZFSekeleton" representation.

2. In the ZF2 tutorial they create two php files under /model called Album.php and AlbumTable.php. I have reflected this is my /Entity folder. Is this direct transfer correct? Does having an /Entity directory render the /model not necessary?

Answer:
Technically you can put your business logic anywhere as long as it follows namespace / psr-0 standards.  Beyond that there is no real requirements, although what is important to you use a coder is that you improve readability of your code or you won't get anywhere fast.

I normally like to seperate my src folders like so:

Controllers
Models
Adapters
Services
Entities

Where controllers is obviously the controllers for zf2.  Models contains some business logic for controllers or classes.  Adapters are authentication adapters, database adapters etc.  Services are the service locator classes for other modules and the current module to work from.  Entities are my data representations.

To each their own but that just makes sense to me.  Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks Will, the learning curve of moving to MVC is intimidating, even for a programmer well versed in procedural php. So I think based on what you say, keep the application as modular as possible!? To answer your question re Users, initially the class would be to define the User and update the db to store their characteristics, but later may be used for authentication etc. I will do some more reading up on module services.

Comment: You're welcome, zf2 definitely does have a big learning curve and the documentation isn't very hit or miss.  Big thing is to conform to psr-0 and remember your namespaces in classes.  Besides Controllers directory the rest of the naming doesn't really matter what you call the other folders that contain your business logic as long as it contains proper namespaces.  And get use to the zf2 classmap autoloader will save you a lot of headaches over standard autoloader

Answer (score 1):

Well-written and nicely formatted question. Don't see that too often.

1. The higher-level one is right. The one that's at the same level as `src`. Everything under src will be class files. So they follow the [PSR-0](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-0/) standard, each file contains excatly one class, etc. So you don't want any views there.
2. Seems pretty good to be, but sice I use Doctrine instead of ZF2's ORM, I can't tell for sure. What I can tell you is that you don't need a `model` directory and that will probably put all of your entities inside `Module\Entity`. So that's absolutely right.

Overall I'd tell you this: Stick with the `config`, `src`, `view` folders. That's what ZF2 likes and this is what every other ZF2 developer will expect from a ZF2 module. Don't get too hung up on conventions inside your `src` folder though. You can pretty much put your stuff whereever you want in there. If you've got a decent IDE (like [PhpStorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/)), it only takes a couple of seconds to move or rename classes later. Just go through some ZF2 modules on GitHub and try to match what groupings or hierarchies you see most often.

And here are some words about the separation of modules: I'd say it's a good practice to try and break your project up into modules as much as possible, as long as you think they could live separately. For example: You have an online shop with a bunch of products and a search function. Now ask yourself the following question: "Do the products *need* the search function?" No. The products can live without it. So you put the search functionality in its own `ProductSearch` module. Can blog posts live without their comments? Yes. Create a `Blog` and a `BlogComment` module.

The whole project structure is something I was thinking a lot about when I started out with ZF2. So if you have any more questions, just comment and I'll try to update my answer.

Comment: Thanks Rudolph, a very useful reply and thanks for noticing that I took time to make sure the questions was written properly!! I see from both of the answers that I have got, more separation the better. And also that ZF2 is open to more interpretation / flexibility than I thought with regards to `/src`

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely read this post: http://akrabat.com/zend-framework-2/thoughts-on-module-directory-structure/